# Is there a xianxia role playing game?

Tags: system-for-setting

I am reading a lot of xianxia light novels nowadays. A description of [xianxia](http://www.wuxiaworld.com/wuxia-vs-xianxia/) can be found here. I am including relevant parts below also.

> As for Xianxia, the characters forming it are ‘Xian’ and ‘Xia’, which
>   literally means ‘immortal hero’.  Xianxia is a newer genre and is
>   essentially a ‘fantasy-fied’ version of Wuxia, with magic, demons,
>   immortals, people who can fly, etc.  The biggest contributor to the
>   Xianxia genre is actually not martial arts; rather, it is ‘Taoism’,
>   which is a major part of Chinese history.  Taoism is both a
>   philosophical way of life as well as an actual religion.  Religious
>   Taoism is often blurred together with Chinese folk mythologies, and is
>   chock-full of stories about demons, ghosts, and people learning how to
>   become immortals through meditation/understanding the ways of heaven,
>   and flying in the air and casting powerful magic spells.

Basically in this novels people level up. Those who can level up called as cultivators and very different from mortals. They have different names for levels but most of the time it is same. When you gain levels, you power up. For example one of the popular novels I shall seal the heavens have following level descriptions. Other novels may have different names for levels but idea remains same.

[Level Descriptions](http://www.wuxiaworld.com/issth-index/issth-glossary-of-terms-places-and-people/)

- Qi Condensation (ningqi) – Nine levels (in modern times); Thirteen
  levels (in ancient times)
- Foundation Establishment (zhuji) – Perfect
  (not seen since ancient times), Flawless (considered the best in
  modern times), Cracked, Fractured
- Core Formation (jiedan) Purple, Crimson, Mottled Nascent Soul (yuanying)
- Spirit Severing (zhanling)
- Seeking the Dao (wendao)
- Immortal Ascension (chengxian)

Difference between normal D&D and Xianxia is that there exist very LARGE gap between these levels for example any Foundation Establishment cultivator can deal with large number of Qi Condensation cultivators.

There are also a lot of items which are similar to D&D, for example Bag of Holding. What I wonder is:

**Are there any role playing games that specifically claim to cover the xianxia genre?**

Comment: This is a really interesting question that we're unfortunately unable to host. I look forward to seeing it show up on one of the forums I read, though!

Comment: Are you asking if there's a game specifically made for xianxia, or if there's a game that could be easily adapted to it?

Comment: Actually both is ok for me.

Comment: Only asking if there is one specifically for that property is on topic (it would be a product identification question)

Comment: @Tritium21 I changed tag to product identification.

Comment: You would actually have to do more editing to make it actually fit the product identification guidelines

Comment: This is not a typical product identification as such, which tends to take the form of "I remember this thing, what is it?" (see the tag description). It's also not our typical recommendation... we presently can't recommend you a system that could be adapted to Xianxia (that's _definitely_ off topic under current policies), but if there is a game that exactly is designed specifically for Xianxia, like an explicit franchise game, that becomes a bit more constructive and answerable, and not exactly our usual shopping question. Interesting. This may be viable.

Comment: Yeah - I'm torn.  I have edited this to be more "no/yes and here's an example" but I am worried questions like this will just turn into the earlier, bad form of game-recs. I will not reopen, but if the community reopens then I will curate it closely as a possible example of a legit kind of question. Might be worth a meta discussion as well.

Comment: That is definitely the wrong tag. I can't think of a replacement tag that isn't [game-rec] or [game-list] or [game-search] or something similarly off topic though.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie I've edited it to just use system-for-setting for now.

Comment: @doppelgreener That's still a game-rec though. I don't see a way to make this work here; it's just not what RPG.se does well.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie I don't think this is our usual game rec, on the basis this is answered by objective fact: "yes there is, it is this one." We aren't recommending arbitrary systems that could do it, nor are we even necessarily recommending the game, just saying that based on our research, it exists, here it is.

Comment: @doppelgreener That's a list question then, though. (A list containing only 1 today, left open, will keep collecting new games as people discover/make/mistake them.) Any way you slice it, it's what we don't do.

Comment: I know of a system that's broken into tiers like that, but it's not actually about Xianxia, but it could probably fit it fairly well. Would it be off topic to mention it?

Comment: @EpsilonRose Yaeah, it'd be off topic. There's a whole bunch of systems where different power levels represent massive jumps in ability, so it'd fall afoul of the same list question problem mentioned by SevenSidedDie.

Comment: Well, even more to the point, "sure, I know a game that can be adapted to match your experience" is a run-of-the-mill game recommendation situation, and we're not doing those anymore.